# How to automatically identify the edge or the FFT points

Tags: dm-script

Hi, all:

I'd like to develop a script to automatically calibrate the pixel size of different mag. Basically, I will face two issues:

1. Identify the edge of stripes (Mag*I*CAL sample), and calculate the average distance between two stripes.
2. Identify the FFT points of Silicon 110 face.

If someone knows open-source script with similar functions, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Regards

Chen ZX

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too broad and asking for an application solution (or opinion based suggestion) rather than a specific coding question based in Digital Micrograph Scripting. The question is interesting (and actually answered), but nevertheless does not belong here.

Comment: I second your vote.

Comment: How to close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question, but one that goes well beyond the scope of DM scripting. You are basically asking about algorithms for edge, peak, and generalized feature detection, a common problem in many types of data analysis. Once you've studied these problems for a while, you will see that, although they seem like simple problems for the sort of intelligence we have on-board in our brains, it is not an easy matter to design a computer algorithm that robustly finds such features in all cases and contexts. In fact, it is with these sorts of problems that many of the developments in artificial intelligence got their start.

In my opinion, it is not likely that you will find this sort of feature detection encapsulated in simple functions, unless your data are unusually simple and clean. Good luck with your further research and developments for your specific data analysis problems. You have joined a pretty large and active community, one that extends well beyond DM scripting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found there is some python modules, such as crystalmaths, which can calculate the lattice distance from FFT image. But it still needs some manual action.